# List View in alphabetical order

Tags: java, android, listview, alphabetical

I have created a android list view in Eclipse that I would like to to sort the data entered in alphabetical order by the first character. Not sure how to accomplish this.

```
private ListView loginL;
private Button bLogin;

private ListAdapter loginListAdapter;

private ArrayList<LoginDetails> loginArrayList;

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_listview);


    loginL = (ListV)
```

findViewById(R.id.loginlist);
        loginL.setOnItemClickListener(this);

```
    bLogin = (Button)
```

findViewById(R.id.button3);
        webLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

```
    loginArrayList = new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();
    loginLAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    loginL.setAdapter(loginLAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Possible repost? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815423/sorting-arraylist-in-android-in-alphabetical-order-case-insensitive  ... only difference is you get your array list as the contents of your listview, if you don't already have the contents as an array list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29). From the doc:

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the
>   natural ordering of its elements

```
Collections.sort(loginArrayList )
```

Comment: implements the above suggestions but the results are the same. Listview is not sorted in alphabetical order. I’m sure this is simple but my minimal experience with this it not allowing me to implement properly. Any assistance or direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

From your arraylist `ArrayList<LoginDetails> loginArrayList;`

i preffered you to use [Comparator.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
  Collections.sort(loginArrayList,new Comparator<LoginDetails>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(LoginDetails lhs, LoginDetails rhs) {

        return lhs.name.compareTo(rhs.name);

    }
});
```