# How to properly sort upper and lowercase Strings in Array in Android?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting arraylist in Android in alphabetical order (case insensitive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815423/sorting-arraylist-in-android-in-alphabetical-order-case-insensitive)

Hi everybody I have a small problem in sorting.

I am taking one collection of type String. When I am sorting it is giving me the wrong result that I was expecting

Here is my code :

```
List <String> caps = new ArrayList<String>();  
caps.add("Alpha");  
caps.add("Beta");  
caps.add("alpha1");  
caps.add("Delta");  
caps.add("theta");  

Collections.sort(caps);
```

It is sorting like:

Alpha 
Beta 
Delta 
alpha1 
theta.

Here it can take any type of string even uppercase / lowercase. But the lowercase words are coming later.

I want the out put like :

Alpha 
alpha1 
Beta 
Delta 
theta

Is there an easy built-in method for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Collections.sort();` lets you pass a custom comparator for ordering. For case insensitive ordering `String` class provides a static final comparator called `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`.

So in your case all that's needed is:

`Collections.sort(caps, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`

Comment: You can do this with arrays as well......Arrays.sort(files, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Comparator`:

```
Collections.sort(caps, new Comparator<String>{
    public int compare(String s1, String s2){
        return s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase());
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `compareToIgnoreCase` instead of this answer.

Comment: @Mordechai's approach as well as `compareToIgnoreCase` are not correct, since both return `0` when comparing `"a"` and `"A"`. In a sorting context, this is not correct. Upper- and lower case versions of a character should be put in a well-defined order.