# Sorting subset of string array in Java, ignoring case

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to properly sort upper and lowercase Strings in Array in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314398/how-to-properly-sort-upper-and-lowercase-strings-in-array-in-android)

I have to sort subset of CLI arguments alphabetically. So, to sort subset the following code is used:

```java
// Ignore args[0], sort the rest
Arrays.sort(args, 1, args.length);
```

And to sort ignoring case, I have to use some sort of comparator object. To sort subset with comparator, there is the following method signature:

```java
Arrays.sort(array, from, to, comp);
```

Can it be done without creating comparator object on separate line, and include it in the Arrays.sort() signature (*i.e.* neat and understandable enough)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [built in comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`:

```
Arrays.sort(args, 1, args.length, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define and initialise an anonymous class implementing `Comparator` e.g.

```
new Comparator<Whatever> {
   public int compare(Whatever w1, Whatever w2) {
      // implementation
   }
   // etc...
}
```

and do this *inline* i.e. within the `Arrays.sort()` method.

```
Arrays.sort(array, from, to, new Comparator<Whatever>{....});
```

The downside is readability if the comparator implementation is non-trivial, and, of course, you can't use that comparator elsewhere. However if the comparator is particularly small, it may aid readability since the implementation is clearly visible.

Comment: Non-trivial indeed. :) However, nice to know the options available for more advanced stuff.