# How to sort certain range of elements only of a String array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

For example I have an array of 5 elements and i want to sort only elements 1-3??

array={"abc","rst","pqr","qwerty","lmn"}

my array should be
array={"abc","pqr","qwerty","rst","lmn"}
How do i proceed?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Following up on what PKR said...  The hover-text for the downvote button begins, "This question does not show any research effort...".  If you put no effort into this, why should we?

Comment: @Sparky:  Ameya Sinah is asking about Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: (Thanks to @KevinJ.Chase) You might want to look at the following discussions about sorting arrays of strings, and sorting subsets of arrays of strings in Java (not JavaScript!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335233/sorting-subset-of-string-array-in-java-ignoring-case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986386/sorting-an-array-of-strings-with-java

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a function that could do it. I knew about Arrays.sort but not that it accepts parameters. I had googled it but did not find anything substantial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[],%20int,%20int)) accepts range parameters.

Example sorting array indexes 1 until 3 inclusive:

```
String[] arr = {"abc", "rst", "pqr", "qwerty", "lmn"};
Arrays.sort(arr, 1, 4);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: All right thanks this is what i wanted to know :)