# Sort list view results by alphabetical order and search function

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a contact manager function within my android application (created using android studio. At the moment I have the contacts showing up in a list view, as seen in the code snippet:

```
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/ivContactImage"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contact Name"
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:textColor="#040000"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone"
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"
        android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address"
        android:id="@+id/cAddress"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to sort these results by alphabetical order if possible? and implement a search bar function, where you can search all contacts on the list. I'm not quite sure where to start.

I have been following this tutorial so far - https://youtu.be/Aqzo_a6Bh4g?list=PL_PaSTBkUwk4PXlhZIe4COpwnWeCRnw2F

My main activity java code:

```
    EditText nameTxt, phoneTxt, emailTxt, addressTxt;
    ImageView contactImageimgView;
    List<Contact> Contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    ListView contactListView;
    Uri imageUri = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list);

        nameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        phoneTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
        emailTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        addressTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
        contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        contactImageimgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewContactImage);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

        tabHost.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Creator");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabCreator);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("add contact");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("List");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabContactList);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("contact list");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);


        final Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Contacts.add(new Contact(nameTxt.getText().toString(), phoneTxt.getText().toString(), emailTxt.getText().toString(), addressTxt.getText().toString(), imageUri));
                populateList();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nameTxt.getText().toString() + " has been added to your Contacts!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        nameTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
                addBtn.setEnabled(!nameTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        contactImageimgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Contact Image"), 1);

            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
        if (resCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (reqCode == 1) {
                imageUri = data.getData();
                contactImageimgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
            }
        }
    }

    private void populateList() {
        ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ContactListAdapter();
        contactListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
        public ContactListAdapter() {
            super (ContactList.this, R.layout.listview_item, Contacts);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null)
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

            Contact currentContact = Contacts.get(position);

            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            name.setText(currentContact.getName());
            TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
            phone.setText(currentContact.getPhone());
            TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
            email.setText(currentContact.getEmail());
            TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cAddress);
            address.setText(currentContact.getAddress());
            ImageView ivContactImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivContactImage);
            ivContactImage.setImageURI(currentContact.get_imageURI());

            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

Error when implementing java.util.Collections.Sort(Contacts)

> Error:(123, 34) error: no suitable method found for sort(List)
>   method Collections.sort(List,Comparator) is not applicable
>   (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   method Collections.sort(List) is not applicable
>   (inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
>   inferred: Contact
>   bound(s): Comparable)
>   where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
>   T#1 extends Object declared in method sort(List,Comparator)
>   T#2 extends Comparable declared in method sort(List)

Comment: What kind of object is used with all of the contact info of each user. i.e. arraylist of contact objects?

Comment: There is no `ListView`in what you're showing?! Also where you get the data from? Depending on data source you may want to use different strategies to filter and sort, e.g. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#restarting vs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#sort%28java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29

Comment: @DavidZafrani Actually I think it is an array list, please check the question I have updated it

Comment: Check answer [sorting in alphabatical order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815423/sorting-arraylist-in-alphabetical-order-case-insensitive)

Comment: @AmitVaghela When using the java.util.Collections.Sort(List) I get the error shown above in the updated question

Comment: Replace contact with another class (that extends contact) and override that classes compareTo