# How to get list of songs using mediastore in alphabetically order

Tags: android, mediastore

How to get a list of songs using mediastore in alphabetical order.
I get all songs using mediastore in an arraylist but this is not in alphabetical order how to get it or how to sort arraylist in alphabetical order

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815423/sorting-arraylist-in-alphabetical-order-case-insensitive refer this to sort arraylist of your songs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sort at source, ie when you execute the query. The last parameter is the one to specify your sort. For example:

```
sort_order = AudioColumns.ARTIST + " DESC, "
                    + AudioColumns.TRACK + " DESC";


context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        dataColumns,
                        selection, selectionArgs,
                        sort_order);
```