# How set the first element in a spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

in my app `Android` I have a set of data I want to bind to a spinner.
But of these I would like a particular value to be seen as the first in the spinner list.

```
public String [] getDescriptionCategories () {
     Set <String> categories = products.keySet ();
     String [] result = new String [categorie.size ()];
     int i = 0;
     for (String cat: categories) {
         result [i ++] = cat;
     }

     return result;
 }
```

The result is `["Altro","Prodotti","Utenti"]`, but I wish it was `["Utenti", "Prodotti", "Altro"]`

How do I set it up?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one

Comment: sort list by order

Answer (score 0):

You should use `return Collections.reverse(result);`. It will reverse your list. If you want to sort the list by alphabetical order, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5815474/8906488). Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Collection class ie   sort(List) and reverse(List)