# sorting user list to alphabetical order in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a chat application and want to arrange user in users list from firebaseStore in alphabetical order. if new users register with the application, these users will be added to the list automatically and arrange in alphabetical order ( like A to B to C, ..).  I try to search the answer but I don't find the solution to my issue. Can anyone help me with how to solve it?

Here is my java code in Userfragment.java:

```
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    mUsers = new ArrayList<>();



    imageProfile = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    username = view.findViewById(R.id.username);

    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid()).orderByChild("username");


    Collections.sort(mUsers, new Comparator<User>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(User lhs, User rhs) {
            return lhs.getUsername().compareTo(rhs.getUsername());
        }
    });

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (isAdded()) {

                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                if (user.getImageUrl().equals("default")) {
                    imageProfile.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                } else {
                    Glide.with(getContext()).load(user.getImageUrl()).into(imageProfile);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

[image: export Json file]

below is some users in realtime database which I want to arrange:

> Users
> 7HMH8nj6AshgYtvD2IMT9a7y2273
> id  "7HMH8nj6AshgYtvD2IMT9a7y2273"
> imageUrl    "default"
> search  "tony"
> status  "online"
> username    "Tony"
> AY3gY1eQE1fWJiNUsxxRqpXHBFf2
> id  "AY3gY1eQE1fWJiNUsxxRqpXHBFf2"
> imageUrl    "default"
> search  "hola"
> status  "offline"
> username    "hola"
> O6gRe8muq4TGDjQsYkn9Cdpufdy1
> id  "O6gRe8muq4TGDjQsYkn9Cdpufdy1"
> imageUrl    "default"
> search  "chon"
> status  "offline"
> username    "chon"
> SGQwWbIZ2vhkPcKqjMuejusKRY13
> id  "SGQwWbIZ2vhkPcKqjMuejusKRY13"
> imageUrl    "default"
> search  "miko"
> status  "offline"
> username    "miko"

Comment: What is the problem with the code you shared. Specifically: if you step through it line by line in a debugger and check each variable on each line, what is the first line where you don't get the value that you expect?

Comment: It really isn't clear what you're asking, but.. you mentioned something vaguely about wanting to sort something, there's an `ArrayList` called "mUsers", so I'm making a leap that you want to sort "mUsers". If that's the case, take a look at: [Sorting arraylist in alphabetical order (case insensitive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815423/sorting-arraylist-in-alphabetical-order-case-insensitive) (or a number of other posts relating to sorting an `ArrayList` using a custom comparator).

Comment: I try using the suggestion from you but it can't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("username");
```

[Learn more here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)

Comment: @MrTony No need gradle. Add your  readusers() functionality here

Comment: I added Readuser() functionality  for your reference. Please help me see where is the errors. thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried and my app was crashed after loading.

Comment: Update your question and your log details

Comment: hi. Gobu CSG, I update my code and get the errors in my question. can you please help to see how to do.

Comment: I think read reference something wrong... Try getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("username")... Are you fetching single user!?... Complete list only right!!!

Comment: orderByChild enough no need collectors callabck

Comment: I remove collectors callback and my application still get crash and it show the error at the code you just give to me:  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.database.Query cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference

Comment: Do you've debug skill!? Firebase reference issue happening...

Comment: Sorry, I am beginner. many things I don't know. hope you can help me

Comment: Enable debug in your phone... If you're using emulator not required  watch enable debug: https://youtu.be/UuLdD7oyML8

Comment: Debugging: https://youtu.be/rjlhSDhFwzM

Comment: yes, So what will I do next to arrange user list as alphabetical order?

Comment: Fix the issue you'll get alphabet... orderByChild will sort your datasnapshot

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.database.Query cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference

Because of the following line of code:

```
reference = (DatabaseReference) FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid()).orderByChild("username");
```

And this is because you are trying to cast an object of type [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) to an object of type [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference), which is actually not possible in Java. The inheritance relationship is as follows, DatabaseReference extends Query and not the opposite.

To solve the problem, you should remove the cast to DatabaseReference and set the type of the object to be Query:

```
Query query =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid()).orderByChild("username");
```

Comment: Thanks Alex Mamo for your guideline. the errors above disappear when I executive your code. Unfortunately, userlist still arrange disorder. there is no change in alphabetical order. Can you please give me other solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "arrange disorder"? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I mean user list appear not follow alphabetical order like A to B to C.

Comment: In that case, as requested before, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Yes, I exported JSON file from Firebase console and what will I do next? if new user arise in the future do the new users will be automatically arranged in alphabetical order with old users?

Comment: Add it to your question, so we can see it. We see what we can do, after we see the schema.

Comment: yes, I updated information my question

Comment: No, please edit your question and add **your database structure** as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data), or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: I clicked the Export JSON in Firebase Console at menu (⠇) and it create JSON file to save my computer. I don't know what to do with this file? I don't what to do with this file.

Comment: Simply open it, and add the content to your question.

Comment: do I have to copy all content of this Json file and paste to my question?  there are a lot data inside it.

Comment: No, only a few children, to see what it looks like. Ok?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question and add some children of user information in Firebase. I am newbie if you need something else, please tell me. Thanks for your great patient with my question.

Comment: Have you also tried to use this query, `Query query =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByChild("username");` and iterate through the results?

Comment: Yes, I tried and posted that code in my question. the result is not changed

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: the issue has not yet solved, sir