# How can I sort a string with integers in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, ascii, compareto

I have got an array. Each space in my array holds two strings (one string contains just letters, the other one numbers).

What I am trying to do now is to sort the array either alphabetically or numerically (depending on which space in the array is chosen). To do that, I am using the compareTo() method. However, I found that when I try to sort the array according to the numbers, it actually does not really work.

My guess is, that since Java handles strings with the ascii codes, numbers don't show up  in numerical order.

Question: How can I fix that?

Comment: can you show some codes? for example how does your array look like? what do you mean "depending on which space in the array is chosen"?

Comment: The order that this function might take care of is the `lexicographical` order of the string. This means indeed using the ascii code of each character.

Comment: ascii codes of (single digit) numbers do show up in numerical order

Comment: @szegedi No, if you sort three strings such as "String 1", "String 2" and "String 12", "String 12" will come before "String 2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `compareTo()` method, when you detect that you are looking at two strings representing integers, make sure they are the same length before comparing them. If one string is shorter, prepend leading zeros to it until the strings are of equal length.

For example, `32` and `123` used to not compare correctly with the default algorithm: `3` is greater, so `32` compares as being after `132`. However, once you prepend zero, the comparison works again: `032` is less than `123`.

Answer (score 2):

For comparing Numbers, may be this will helpful.

The Alphanum Algorithm

From the website : http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

People sort strings with numbers differently than software. Most sorting algorithms compare ASCII values, which produces an ordering that is inconsistent with human logic. Here's how to fix it.

Here's a link to the Java Comparator Implementation from that site.
http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.java

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, Strings are sorted according to their Unicode codepoint value. This means that "2" is smaller than "a" and larger than "11".

I suspect that you are looking for a *Natural Sort Order*. A great SO post detailling about it is [Java String Number Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270447/java-string-number-comparator) and you can find actual implementations in the SO post [Natural sort order string comparison in Java - is one built in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262239/natural-sort-order-string-comparison-in-java-is-one-built-in)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Long(or)Folat.isNaN() method to check its number or sting then by using that you can do your sorting.

Answer (score 0):

When sorting numerically convert strings to numbers before comparing them.