# Take input files same in the order as in directory

Tags: java

I'm writing a code where in there a bunch of files that have to be taken as input from a directory.

The program works fine, but the problem comes up in the way the files are picked. In my directory when I do a sort the first file shown is `file5521.3`, but in my program the first file that is picked up is `file5521.100`. THis is pretty confusing.

I've also tried using `Arrays.sort(list, NameFileComparator.NAME_COMPARATOR)`, but it also gives the same result as previous.

Below is my code.

```
void countFilesInDirectory(File directory, String inputPath) throws IOException {
    File[] list = directory.listFiles();
    Arrays.sort(list, NameFileComparator.NAME_COMPARATOR);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
    tempPath = inputPath.substring(0, inputPath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1) + "OP\\";
    File outPath = new File(tempPath);
    if (!outPath.exists()) {
        outPath.mkdir();
    }
    File temp = new File(tempPath + "temp.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);

    if (!temp.exists()) {
        temp.createNewFile();
    }
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(list[i]);
        setStatusText(i);
        GenerateFiles(list[i].getAbsoluteFile().toString(), bw);
    }
    bw.write("</body>");
    bw.close();
    File newFile = new File(temp.getParent(), "Index.html");
    Files.move(temp.toPath(), newFile.toPath());
}
```

please let me know how can I do this.

**Working Solution with Last Modified Date**

```
Arrays.sort(list, new Comparator<File>() {
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                return Long.compare(f1.lastModified(), f2.lastModified());
            }
        });
```

The `Comparator` works fine with last modified date, but when I try it with below code. The result is same as previous.

```
Arrays.sort(list, new Comparator<File>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }

        });
```

In my Windows Explorer It looks like below. I've sorted the filenames.

[image]

And my console output shows the below.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why does the order of processing matter? And if it does, then the file name convention should reflect that to avoid differences in directory and string based sorting so that it is unequivocally the same.

Comment: what is your OS, what do you mean by "In my directory **when I do a sort** the first file shown is"?

Comment: The order of files is going to be determined by whatever software you use to view them (e.g. Explorer on Windows). You'll need to use a comparator that uses that same logic.

Comment: Hi @RC. I mean that In my Windows Explorer when I click the title bar, the names gets sorted.

Answer (score 1):

[If your OS is Windows XP or later, your files will be sorted using Numerical File Name Sorting.](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-numerical-file-name-sorting-and-enable-classic-literal-sorting-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7-explorer/)

Since you want to match the file order both in the program and in your File Explorer, you can either:

1. Follow the steps in the link to use Classical Literal Sorting which will change the way File Explorer displays files.
2. Create a custom `Comparator` that you pass into `sort` that will sort based on the actual VALUE of the number (e.g. 3 would come before 10 because 3 < 10)

Comment: Hi Chara, I tried this, but still there is no change in result :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Apache Commons IO** to sort files using many predefined `Comparator`s or even combine these using `CompositeFileComparator`

Here is an example:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.comparator.*;

File dir = new File(".");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
File[] filesSorted = DefaultFileComparator.DEFAULT_COMPARATOR.sort(files);
File[] filesReversed = DefaultFileComparator.DEFAULT_REVERSE.sort(files);
```

... and [here is the list of available comparators](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/comparator/package-frame.html)

Comment: When I do this, it is throwing me some error Saying `The method sort(File[]) is undefined for the type Comparator<File>`

Comment: Hi friend, I've updated my question with the code that I've tried. Can you please look into it.

Comment: @Rakesh what you see is the result of lexical sort. Sorting strings using lexical sorts makes the following A1 < A11 < A11112 < A12 < A9. Windows file browser is not using lexical order but natural ordering (when seeing numbers in parts of text it will use numerical ordering. You would have to create your own comparator implementing human natural order sorting. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270447/java-string-number-comparator