# How to use java's sort function in a way that it will sorts 2 before 11?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I am using the following java code to sort the values: -

```
 Collections.sort(values);
```

It is working correctly except that it is sorting as follows: - 
1 10 2 3 4

I need it to sort as follows: -
1 2 3 4 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting `Strings`. You can change values to store a subclass of `Number` or implement your own `Comparator` to pass as the segment argument of the `sort` method which will do a "natural sort."

See this question for more details: [Natural sort order string comparison in Java - is one built in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262239/natural-sort-order-string-comparison-in-java-is-one-built-in)

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) into the `sort` call to convert the string into a number during the sort, or store the value as a number in the first place. When comparing strings, `10` comes before `2`.

Alternatively, define a `compareTo` in your class (and have the class it implement [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)) if you always need to sort the same way, and skip the `Comparator`.

Comment: then just compare lengths before lexicographically (properly trimmed of course)

Comment: unless you are micro optimizing and can't afford parsing the string

Answer (score 1):

Use a `List<Integer>` (not a `List<String>` which it looks like you are using).