# Is there a Comparator to "naturally" sort strings that may contain numbers, guava?

Tags: java, string, sorting, guava

Is there a `Comparator` implementation in [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to sort strings in a "natural" way that may contain numbers? 

Eg:
"a 8"
"a 9"
"a 10"

I found some interesting links regarding this, but it looks like there is nothing in guava to do the job...

StackOverflow: ["Sort on a String that may contain a number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number)
A good explanation of the: [The Alphanum Algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)

Comment: What's wrong with the `Alphanum Algorithm`? It seems to be what you want. And why do you need "Guava"? Just use `Collections.sort(list, comparator);`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with "Alphanum Algorithm", i don't want to reeinvent the wheel (if there is a wheel)! `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` needs the `Comperator` i'am asking for.

Comment: Is downloading the [pre-written java](http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.java) (albeit non-generic) really "reinventing the wheel"? Perhaps, but it's certainly "low hanging fruit".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262239/natural-sort-order-string-comparison-in-java-is-one-built-in) which links to an [open-source implementation](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Science/Cougaar12_4/org/cougaar/util/NaturalOrderComparator.java.htm)

Comment: I'am looking for a pure Guava solution, because i don't want to wrap every opensource lib to a osgi-bundle, just for one useful feature! Guava has many great features just in one jar. Give it a try, you won't regret it.

Comment: @Chriss OSGi bundle? One source file?! Pity I cannot -1 you.

Comment: @alf Sorry, i am not a native speaker. Of cause i dont want to wrap one class in one bundle. Also i don't want to put 100 classes of a opensource-lib in one bundle, only to use 1 class out of 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't any built in implementation of such a comparator in Guava... seems like something that's too narrowly applicable to me. Just write your own implementation or use one of the existing ones that have been linked already.

Comment: Speaking as a Guava developer, we don't do anything that's quite this narrow-purpose.

Comment: Ok, i thought it is such a common use case, that there must be a solution already in guava

Answer (score 0):

Take a look 
http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/util/NumericUtils.html

Comment: Thanks, as explained earlier I am looking for a Guava solution.