# TreeMap doesn't sort properly in this case

Tags: java, sorting

Sequence of statements to copy `HashMap` to `TreeMap`

```
private Map<String,Bitmap> imageFilexx= new HashMap<String,Bitmap>();

//Assuming map has values
printMap(imageFilexx);
TreeMap<String,Bitmap> imageFilexxS;
imageFilexxS= new TreeMap<String,Bitmap>(imageFilexx);
printMap(imageFilexxS);
```

**Function To Display Above Map:**

```
public static void printMap(Map<String, Bitmap> map) {
        for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey());
        }
    }
```

**Input:**

```
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p7.png  
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p1.png 
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p5.png 
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p3.png 
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p11.png 
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p9.png
```

**Current O/P:**

```
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p1.png
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p11.png //11 should be displayed in the last 
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p3.png 
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p5.png
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p7.png
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p9.png
```

**Expected O/P:**

```
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p1.png
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p3.png 
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p5.png
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p7.png
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p9.png
Key : http://myserver.com/myfolder/ImageDesc/ImageDesc%20p11.png
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is sorting lexicographically (the [default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) sort method).

You'll have to define your own implementation of a [natural sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262239/natural-sort-order-string-comparison-in-java-is-one-built-in).  The constructor of `TreeMap` allows you to pass in your custom comparator.

Comment: Thanks for NaturalOrderComparator. `imageFilexxS= new TreeMap<String,Bitmap>(new NaturalOrderComparator());` is constructor to my new `Treemap` now. But how do I use it to sort my existing map from it.

Comment: Add the members from your existing map to that map (or just use the naturally ordered map across the code).

Comment: Yeah I did that , Thanks for your reply I learned something today.