# Best way to sort a String ArrayList with numbers in it

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an array list that is set up in this type of style...

- 4 dogs
- 10 cats
- 2 dogs

And I want to sort it so the ArrayList will be in the order of...

- 1 dogs
- 4 dogs
- 10 cats

Without using a comparator or another method, what is the shortest, easiest way to sort these by taking out the numbers (splitting the string by the space " "?), comparing them, and putting the sorted results back into the ArrayList? If you could attach your code snippet, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an Arraylist that contains strings with numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669270/sorting-an-arraylist-that-contains-strings-with-numbers)

Comment: Makes no sense to me that you don't want to use a Comparator. Someone has to compare the items, no? How else would you deduce which item is bigger.

Comment: comparator is best way of sorting. Use it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the definition of comparator. This is exactly what I meant. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to use comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    public void compare(String one, String two) {
         return getNumber(one) - getNumber(two);
    }
    private int getNumber(String str) {
        return Integer.parseInt(one.split(" ")[0]);
    }
}
```

I really do not know what can be simpler.

Comment: Thanks so much. Sorry I must of misunderstood the definition of a comparator.

Answer (score 2):

Without an explicit Comparator, try using Java 8's Lambda feature:

```
//Assuming that the list variable is a string that looks like e.g. "1 10 2 5"

Arrays.sort(list.split(" "), 
    (String a, String b) -> { return Integer.valueOf(a).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b)) }; 
);

//Assuming that the list variable is an array list of Strings

Collections.sort(list, 
    (String a, String b) -> { return Integer.valueOf(a).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b)) }; 
);
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class have `String` field in that class and implement `compareTo` method and write comparison logic.

Use this class object in `ArrayList` and then use `Collections.sort` method.

Comment: "Without using Comparator, sorting is not possible in Java." Unless you just implement your own sorting algorithm in a method...

Comment: thats for sure :) I meant by using JAVA API.

Comment: "Without using Comparator, sorting is not possible in Java" wrong sentence. You can do it by any method or algorithm.