# How to sort Strings considering the digits inside them?

Tags: java, sql, string, sorting

I have some codes looking like the one of following:

- aaa_bbb_d2_aa
  aaa_bbb_d3_aa
  aaa_bbb_d11_aa
- eee_b2b_c2_ac

In general they should be sorted as strings, however in case of “aaa_bbb_d3_aa” vs.  “aaa_bbb_d11_aa”  the former should come first in contrast to simple string sorting.

The numerical part that is important for sorting always resides after either the “_d” or “_c” substring and always is followed by “_aa” or by “_ac” ending the string.

What is an efficient sorting algorithm in Java or SQL?

Comment: So for your example, it would sort aaa before eee? Or do you want to sort specifically on the _d3 vs _d11 part?

Comment: @anarinsky Do you have any ideas of your own that you would like to share?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1262239/335858).

Comment: try to extract number from string, compare numbers and voilà,
extracting number from a string should be called when your first method cant decide which string should be first

Comment: @WhyCry, yes aaa should be sorted before eee, only strings differ by numerical parts after _d or or _c should be sorted by number

Comment: What trouble did you run into when you implemented your code? Can you give details?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  - yes, your info was helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with NaturalOrderComparator.java:  https://github.com/paour/natorder .
Thanks @dasblinkenlight for the useful comment

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(yourListOfString, (String a, String b) ->
{
    int comparison = Integer.valueOf(a.split("_")[2].replaceAll("[dc]", "")).compareTo(Integer.parseInt(b.split("_")[2].replaceAll("[dc]", "")));

    return comparison == 0
             ? a.split("_")[3].compareTo(b.split("_")[3])
             : comparison;
});
```

(I assume all your strings are in a list)