# Regex match string that end with character but exclusive of that character

Tags: java, regex

I need to match the quality of a film and order them. The value can be found in the title

Ex. `"The Wolf of Wall Street (2014) (HD, 1080p).mov"`

I have a regex that matches the quality:

```
"\\d\\d\\d[\\d]*p"
```

For some reason when i compare (compareTo) the values they are ordered:

Ex.

```
1080p
1080p
480p
480p
480p
720p
720p
```

480p lists higher than 720p. I believe that this happens because of the p(?). I wonder how I can change my regex to check that there is a p (so the year in the title isn't matched, only the quality) but excludes the p in the matched string.

Comment: Lexical ordering, 4 is before 7.

Comment: use `\\d{3.}(?=p)` to match only the numbers

Comment: What is your java code? It could be done without using regex

Comment: Also note that being listed "higher" means that the value compares as *smaller*. Thus "1080" < "480" < "720".

Comment: You might also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262239/natural-sort-order-string-comparison-in-java-is-one-built-in concering natural sorting (what you might search for, if you don't want to compare just the numbers as numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Use can use regex `"(\\d{3,4})p"` to extract number from string with `Matcher.group(1)` and sort them as numbers, not strings. Strings are compared lexicographically.

Comment: Please explain more! What does matcher.group(1) do?

Comment: @kletan it extracts the first capturing group (the string inside parentheses)

Comment: @kletan Matcher created with `Pattern.compile("(\\d{3,4})p)").matcher("The Wolf of Wall Street (2014) (HD, 1080p).mov")` must return `1080` from `matcher.group(1)` after `matcher.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a special `String` comparator, which firstly compare by length, then by value:

```
Comparator<String> LENGTH_FIRST = (s1, s2) -> s1.length() == s2.length() 
                                      ? s1.compareTo(s2) 
                                      : (s1.length() - s2.length());
```

When sorting using such comparator, longer strings (meaning higher quality) become located after shorter:

```
List<String> qualities = Arrays.asList("1080p", "480p", "720p");
Collections.sort(qualities, LENGTH_FIRST); // will re-order as [480p, 720p, 1080p]
```

Comment: This actually works, but I can't really understand why?

Comment: @kletan very simple. For positive integers, any number with more digits is bigger than any number having less digits (`1000` > `999`). Among numbers of same count of digits, bigger is number that is bigger lexicographically.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Java that much, but maybe you could use a group inside the regex?
I.e.:

```
"(\\d\\d\\d[\\d]*)p"
```

And then make a backreference to the group (content inside the parentheses). I know you can do that with perl regex

Hope it helped!